# Unattend.xml user name

Tags: unattended

I'm using an Unatend.xml on my WDS and I have a problem with the username.

This is my Unattend:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <RunSynchronous>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <Path>net user administrator /active:yes</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
            </RunSynchronous>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ShowWindowsLive>false</ShowWindowsLive>
            <TimeZone>Romance Standard Time</TimeZone>
            <CopyProfile>true</CopyProfile>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>es-ES</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>es-ES</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-UK</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>es-ES</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Enabled>false</Enabled>
            </AutoLogon>
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
                <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
                <SkipMachineOOBE>false</SkipMachineOOBE>
                <SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>
            </OOBE>
            <TimeZone>Romance Standard Time</TimeZone>
            <UserAccounts>
                <AdministratorPassword>
                    <Value>password123</Value>
                    <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                </AdministratorPassword>
            </UserAccounts>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="generalize"></settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:e:/images/w7_user/sources/install.wim#Windows 7 Enterprise x64" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

With `<SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>` I want skip the user creation form, and with `<SkipMachineOOBE>false</SkipMachineOOBE>` I want to force a computer name.

The problem is that with this configuration, appear this form:

[image]

And I'm looking for this:

[image]

Why? Because I only want a computer with the user administrator enabled and no more.

Does someone know where the error is?